# Find the length of $2$ points based on intersection of a circle

Tags: calculus, geometry

Would anyone know the formula for finding the length of $BC$ giving the below data.

$AB = 20$

$r = unknown$

$BC = ?$

The other dimensions that can be used if needed are written on the diagram.

Thank you for any help.

[image: intersection and distance of 2 points]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let the center of the circle be labelled $O.$  then $$OA^2 = (100-40)^2 + 50^2=10^2(61)\to OA = r = 10\sqrt{61} $$

and  $$\sin(\angle OCB ) = \frac{30}{r} = \frac{3}{\sqrt{61}}, \cos(\angle OCB ) = \frac{\sqrt{52}}{\sqrt{61}}$$

vertical height of $C$ from the center is $$r\cos(\angle OCB ) =10\sqrt{52}, BC = 10\sqrt{52} - 60=12.111$$

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @Icewine, you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

For clarity, let the foots of the altitudes drawn from the points A & C be D & E respectively & center of circle O.
Using pythagoras theorem in right $\Delta ADO$ (assume in the given figure), we get radius of circle $$OA=\sqrt{(OD)^2+(AD)^2}=\sqrt{50^2+(100-40)^2}=10\sqrt{61}\implies OA=OB=10\sqrt{61}$$
Similarly, using pythagoras theorem in right $\Delta CEO$ (assume in the given figure), we get radius of circle $$CE=\sqrt{(OC)^2-(OE)^2}=\sqrt{(10\sqrt{61})^2+(50-20)^2}=20\sqrt{13}$$ Hence, $$BC=CE-BE=20\sqrt{13}-60\approx 12.11102551$$